# Repeat last shell command shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, shell, shell-command

How can you repeat last shell command with a single shortcut (and no y/n prompts)? How to replace this sequence:

1. <kbd>C-u C-x s</kbd> (or equivalent) to save all buffers
2. <kbd>M-!</kbd> for `(shell-command COMMAND &optional ...)`
3. <kbd>M-p</kbd> for `(previous-history-element N)`
4. <kbd>RET</kbd>

Basically, how can you get this working:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-`") (lambda () (interactive)
              (save-some-buffers)  ;; 1.
              (shell-command nil)  ;; 2.
              (previous-history-element 1)  ;; 3.
              (<press RET>)))  ;; 4.
```

As is, it returns an error: `shell-command: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. What should a `COMMAND` be when calling `(shell-command COMMAND ...)` from ELISP?

---

Somewhat related question:
[Is there a (repeat-last-command) in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275842/is-there-a-repeat-last-command-in-emacs)

Comment: Why don't you just record a keyboard macro and replay that?

Comment: You're right! I was overthinking it. And then just save the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to do this properly in elisp, here's a stab at it:

```
(defun my-repeat-last-shell-command ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers)
  (shell-command (cadr (assoc 'shell-command command-history))))
```

Comment: `(save-some-buffers t)` to prevent from prompting `Save file <filepath>?`.

Comment: This might backfire. How to check that last `(shell-command)` did *not* start with a non-idempotent command like `rm` or `mv`?

Comment: @courteous Well, I'm just transcribing your set of commands in a slightly less literal way. Not prompting on saving (the mere fact that a save is done is somewhat surprising, I wouldn't expect it from that kind of command) is one thing, filtering out unsafe candidates is beyond the scope of this question.